# Django didn't return an HttpResponse object error?

Tags: python, django

```
ValueError at /blog/1/comment/new/

The view blog.views.comment_new didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Request Method: GET

Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/blog/1/comment/new/
```

why is request method get?

**HTML**

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
  </table>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**VIEWS**

```
@login_required
def comment_new(request, post_pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_pk)

    if request.method == 'post':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.save()
            return redirect('blog:post_detail', post.pk)
        else:
            form = CommentForm()
        return render(request, 'blog/comment_form.html', {
            'form': form,
        })`
```

thanks

Comment: why you did not specify anything in action paramter of the html form

Comment: I don't need parameter now.

Comment: you should specify a action url otherwise how will you ensure that there is no extra clutter being sent to the server

Comment: you need the action url in your template form to define the post destination in views, so that the django can know which function you are calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are returning response for post method only. You have to refactor your code like this.

```
def call_comment_form(request): #your function name
    form = CommentForm()
    if request.method == 'post':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.save()
            return redirect('blog:post_detail', post.pk)
        else:
            form = CommentForm(request.post) #this will return the errors in your form
    return render(request, 'blog/comment_form.html', {
    'form': form,
})`
```

when a url is called initially it is GET method so you have to send a instance of form first (empty form).

Comment: This does not answer OP's question completely. OP asked why his request method is get when he did put post in his html form. You might want to refactor this answer to make it complete

Comment: when working with forms if you are requesting for a new entry for the form it will be GET method initially. But where as when u submit the form it should be POST method. We should not submit the form in GET to ensure that data filled in form is not exposed when we are sending back the response to the server.

Comment: yeah correct whatever you are saying about exposing and other. But still you did not answer what i was asking. Also there is a syntax error in your answer `{contextdata:data}` in this line you might want to use contextdata as string or define it as variable

Comment: @JakJu I assume you are new to django. I have updated the functionality check whether it works or not.